# How to add a button into a nother application's window using C#

Tags: c#, window, addition

As the title, I'd like add a button into a window **of another application** and handle it.

The detail is :

- I writing a application running on MS window, when it running, it will find the main window of the appication "Skype". (ofcause, this task will run only when skype running)
- If found, it will add a button into the main window of skype. My application will do something when user press it.

I'm using C#.

Thanks a lot

Comment: There are nowhere near enough details in your question to be able to answer this. What kind of application?

Comment: So you want to push one of your own buttons into another application like Skype, and have it do things, interacting with that application?  Um.. no.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken Skype does have an api that you can program an extension for it.

Comment: To all the closers: what's not clear about this? Seems like a decent question and a decent answer. Nominating for reopening.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this (tested using Skype for Windows Desktop version 6.11.0.102)

```
public void AttachButtonToSkype() {
  // find skype main window (className = tSkMainForm)
  var mainHandle = NativeMethods.FindWindow("tSkMainForm", null);

  if (mainHandle != IntPtr.Zero) {
    // find child window to inject (className = TMyselfControl)
    var parentHandle = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(mainHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "TMyselfControl", null);

    if (parentHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {          
      var button = new Button { Text = "Click Me!", Left = 150, Top = 5, Width = 75, Height = 25 };
      button.Click += (o, args) => { MessageBox.Show("You've clicked me"); };

      NativeMethods.SetParent(button.Handle, parentHandle);
    }
  }
}
```

**NativeMethods**

```
internal class NativeMethods {
  [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string ClassN, string WindN);

  [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

  [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
}
```

Tips: Use [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460756.aspx%20Spy++) to find window className

Comment: I've tested and found an error like this 

An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe

So, I should change the code 

[DllImport("User32.dll, SetLastError = true")]

To

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
        .....

Btw, I voted your answer as Accepted.

Thanks you.

Comment: Oops! I missplaced a quote character there. It should've been `[DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]` not `[DllImport("User32.dll, SetLastError = true")]`. Thank you for accepting it as answer.