# C# disappearing button added to another window

Tags: c#, winapi

I am placing a button in another application window using the code from the link below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21036515/8435498

unfortunately the button is only visible for 2-3 seconds.  then disappears.  How can I find the reason.  I want the button to be visible until the window in which I place it is closed.  Below is a preview of what it looks like.
[image: gif]

Comment: Why would you ever expect that to work anyway? This isn't a supported scenario.

Comment: the button is added but only for a moment.  How should I do this?

Comment: *"How should I do this?"* - Either in native code, from the thread that owns the (designated) parent window, or not at all.

Answer (score 1):

Since the linked code has been accepted and upvoted quite a few times, I assume that adding a button to another process is in principle possible. However, I have not tested it thoroughly and do not know whether this leads to a stable solution.

The button probably disappears because it is in the heap of your application. When the button is not required anymore in your application (e.g. if it has only been declared as a local variable), the Garbage Collector (GC) will remove it when doing the next collection.

Therefore, I suggest calling `GC.KeepAlive`:

```cs
var button = new Button { Text = "test", Left = 150, Top = 5, Width = 75, Height = 25 };
button.Click += (o, args) => { MessageBox.Show("You've clicked me"); };
GC.KeepAlive(button); // <==============

NativeMethods.SetParent(button.Handle, parentHandle);
```

Another possibility is to keep a reference to it in a static field.

However, this will only work as long as your application is running. When it is closed, all the memory (including the button) will be reclaimed by the operating system.

---

I made a little WinForms app that adds a button to notepad to test it. It does indeed work. Note that I am storing the added button to a field of the Form to keep it alive as long as this Form remains open.

```cs
public class FormAddButtonToAnotherApp : Form
{
    private readonly Button _btnAdd;
    private Button? _button;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string? lpszWindow);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    public FormAddButtonToAnotherApp()
    {
        _btnAdd = new Button();
        _btnAdd.Location = new Point(118, 67);
        _btnAdd.Size = new Size(75, 23);
        _btnAdd.Text = "Add";
        _btnAdd.Click += BtnAdd_Click;
        Controls.Add(_btnAdd);
    }

    private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process[] notepads = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
        if (notepads is []) {
            MessageBox.Show("No notepad process found!");
        } else {
            nint mainHandle = notepads[0].MainWindowHandle;
            if (mainHandle != IntPtr.Zero) {
                nint childHandle = FindWindowEx(mainHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "NotepadTextBox", null);
                if (childHandle != IntPtr.Zero) {
                    _button = new Button { Text = "Click Me!", Left = 150, Top = 5, Width = 75, Height = 25 };
                    _button.Click += (o, args) => { MessageBox.Show("You've clicked me"); };

                    SetParent(_button.Handle, childHandle);
                } else {
                    MessageBox.Show("childHandle is Zero");
                }
            } else {
                MessageBox.Show("mainHandle is Zero");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Assuming that the code you linked is working"* - That assumption is [ludicrous](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683).

Comment: @IInspectable. This question is not about whether it is a good idea to add a button to another process or not. I must admit that I do not feel comfortable about this idea, but the linked answer has been accepted and upvoted 11 times as I am writing this. Therefore, it can be assumed that it should work, and I am only answering the question of why the button disappears after a few seconds and how to prevent it.

Comment: The link I posted explains in great detail the bare minimum required to make this work reliably: You have to have full control over *both* threads involved. Obviously, you do not control the thread that owns the Notepad window, and the CLR owns the thread that injects the window. And now you have two input queues of threads you have no control over attached. But since you are hard to convince by words, try your code on Windows 11.

Comment: I am running it under Windows 11. I do not pretend that it is a good idea to do it. The OP does it obviously and I am only trying to solve the specific sub-problem he asked for. The other problems that adding this button might cause are not the subject of this question. If it works it works, if it doesn't it doesn't. What is the worst thing that can happen? A blue screen maybe? The OP will survive this and be one experience richer.

Comment: @IInspectable.
I see your point and wouldn't do this in production code, but it's an interesting experiment. The best way to learn is to do playful things.